# Portable solution to POSIX linux interval timer (timer_create, timer_settime...)

Tags: c, linux, windows, timer, signals

I have a piece of code that use linux POSIX interval timers (timer_create, timer_settime...) that I want to port it to Windows.

Is there a solution that will work on both platforms?

## update:

timer_create will notify the caller by rising a signal or triggering a function when the timer expires

Comment: boost::asio::deadline_timer

Comment: POSIX stuff generally does work on Windows (at least through CygWin).

Comment: Create an implementation of the posix functions that use the windows functions.

Comment: @RichardHodges: The question is C, not C++.

Comment: Windows doesn't have POSIX signals. You'd need a POSIX compatibility library such as MSYS2 or Cygwin, or as suggested above, write your own library just for your own limited needs.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite I see the c++ tag was removed 5 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Through CygWin, POSIX functions generally work on
 both Linux and Windows.

For example, the following compiles and works in Cygwin well:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    timer_t tmr;
    //error checking omitted for brevity
    timer_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, &(struct sigevent){ .sigev_notify=SIGEV_SIGNAL, .sigev_signo=SIGALRM}, &tmr);
    timer_settime(tmr, 0, &(struct itimerspec){ .it_value={.tv_sec=3}}, 0);
    pause(); //will break after 3s
}
```

Answer (score -2):

consider of using `std::chrono` features for c++11
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/

Comment: timer_create will notify the caller by rising a signal or triggering a function when the timer expires. this is not supported by std::chrono

Comment: The question is about C, not C++. This is not even a suitable comment.

Comment: @ too honest for this site I am looking for  c or c++ solution